# auto populating field in excel based on other values from other columns

Tags: excel, autocomplete, calculated-columns

I have an excel sheet that has 16 columns and unlimited rows.  It tracks a product and whether it passed or rejects inspection.  I have 6 columns that have drop downs with the given values: accepted, rejected and missing.  A19 is the product as a whole.  If one of those other columns columns (C19, F19, I19, L19 and O19) is rejected then the entire product (A19) is rejected. Is there a formula that I can apply so that if one of the columns has rejected it auto populates the corresponding cell as rejected?

Say C19, F19, I19, L19 were all accepted but O19 was rejected, I would like A19 to automatically enter rejected.

Comment: new worksheet.  Values are in different columns

Comment: "unlimited rows" - what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Many different formulae are possible, but the following should be one of them:

> =IFERROR(IF(MATCH("rejected",B19:O19)>0,"REJECT"),"")

Comment: It puts down "REJECT" every time.  A19 has the same drop down menu as the others. instead of making it just write text "REJECT" is there a way to allow it to select the value from the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a hidden column after each column which looks up the word in the preceding column and assigns a zero if accepted and a 1 if its rejected.

Then in the final column, get it to add up the hidden columns. If it returns a zero, its accepted. If its greater than zero, its a reject.

So in the hidden column -say D19
=if(C19="accept",0,1)

In A19 
=if((C19+....)>0,"reject","accept")